# Why is CSS background-image not loading when using absolute URL?

Tags: css, background-image, css-position

I've implemented our company's signature in [this](http://www.moteljoanne.com) website's footer.

I'm using this code to do it:

```css
a.logoDSI {
  display: block;
  width: 115px;
  height: 20px;
  background-image: url('http://www.groupedsi.com/images/realise-par/logoDSI_rect-pale.png');
  background-position: 0% 0%;
  text-indent: -999999px;
  margin: 14px 10px 9px 10px;
}

a.logoDSI:hover {
  background-position: 0% -100%;
}
```

```html
<a id="logoeDream" href="http://www.edreamweb.com" title="eDream | Services d'hébergement - eCommerce - Développement mobile" target="_blank"><span>eDream</span></a>
```

The problem is that this works perfectly fine on PC and Mac but when I access this website with an iPod, iPad, or iPhone the logo simply doesn't show. As soon as I change the image path for a relative path the image appears.

Is this normal? Is there a way I can use an absolute path to www.groupedsi.com that will show on mobile devices?

Comment: Do you change the path in live ? Try adding `position: relative;` to the `a.logoDSI`, maybe with a `z-index`.

Comment: Check your CSS. The image is out of the footer.

Comment: Like i said guys as soon as i change the path to a relative one the image appears so it's not a problem about positioning or z-index...

Comment: It could be a bug of the browser. You should really try what I suggest because I tested it, and yes the logo does not show, but as soon as I add `position: relative;` it works. What browser are you using ?

Comment: Just tried it and it doesn't work. I'm using an iPod with Safari for mobile testing. Question tho how could you test position:relative on a mobile device ? Did you use the firebug lite hack ?

Comment: this should work just fine. Have you checked the browser dev tools to see what the request and response look like? Is the browser making a request for this image? Is it calling the correct URL? Is the URL responding with the expected image? Or is it giving a http error code? If so, what is it? This is the kind of detail you need to know in order to debug this kind of thing.

Comment: Just to make sure, were talking about Safari MOBILE browser on iPod. I'm not sure what browser dev tools you are talking about but if you know any that works well on apple MOBILE devices i'd like to know which ones.

Comment: Did you end up finding the solution for this?  We are struggling with the exactly same issue in mobile safari on iPhone 4.

Answer (score 0):

Using Safari 5.0.3 for Windows on my desktop, I couldn't see the [logo](http://www.groupedsi.com/images/realise-par/logoDSI_rect-pale.png) on your home page either, though with Safari 5.1.7, I could. Is Safari up-to-date on your iPod?